# Limit the values used in a function to their sum

Tags: r

I created a function with that I want to calculate (several) vectors of data.
Actually the vctors should be for a range (1:100) for one variable while the others stay constant at differnt values in turn.

The function is:`EI <- function(x,y,z) {(x+y)/(2*(2*x+y)+z)}`

my Problem is, the sum of x+y+z has to be limited to 100. And i don't know how to tell it the function.
For example, if `x = 20`, `y` can only take values from `0:80` , i.e. (100-20), and z can takey values from 0 : 100-(x+y).

I used the following code where z is not regarded all. I thought, I would get at least one large vector, but all I get is a single number:

```
for(x in 1:100) {
        for(y in 0:(100-x)) {
                for(z in 0:(100-(x+y))) {
                v1 <- c(EI(x,y,z))         
        }
}
}
```

I need to tell the function EI() that the sum of x+y+z has alwys to be 100.
Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: in `EI` function throw an error in case sum is not 100? `if(x+y+z !=100) stop("sum xyz must be 100")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a vector you need to do that:

```
v1 <- c()

for(x in 1:100) {
        for(y in 0:(100-x)) {
                for(z in 0:(100-(x+y))) {
                v1 <- c(v1, EI(x,y,z))         
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this will be slow (because at each step you are reallocating a new vector), a better alternative is to begin by allocate your vector with the appropriate size:

```
v1 <- numeric(171700)
k <- 0
for(x in 1:100) {
        for(y in 0:(100-x)) {
                for(z in 0:(100-(x+y))) {
                k <- k + 1
                v1[k] <- EI(x,y,z)         
        }
    }
}
```

You can also write the same thing with `sapply` function and this is slightly faster:

```
v1 <- unlist(sapply(1:100,
             function(x) {
               unlist(sapply(0:(100-x),
                      function(y) {
                        sapply(0:(100-(x+y)),
                               function(z) {EI(x,y,z)}) }))}))
```